# NoClassDefFoundError when using Javacv

Tags: java, javacv

I have tried to use JavaCV to capture snaps from my webcamera.but when i ran below code i got an exeception.It says the class com/googlecode/javacpp/Pointer is not found. What can i do to solve this error...

```
 package camera;

/**
 *
 * @author asankad
 */
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.cvFlip;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.cvSaveImage;

import com.googlecode.javacv.CanvasFrame;
import com.googlecode.javacv.FrameGrabber;
import com.googlecode.javacv.VideoInputFrameGrabber;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IplImage;

public class GrabberShow implements Runnable {
    //final int INTERVAL=1000;///you may use interval
    IplImage image;
    CanvasFrame canvas = new CanvasFrame("Web Cam");
    public GrabberShow() {
        canvas.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        FrameGrabber grabber = new VideoInputFrameGrabber(0); 
        int i=0;
        try {
            grabber.start();
            IplImage img;
            while (true) {
                img = grabber.grab();
                if (img != null) {
                    cvFlip(img, img, 1);// l-r = 90_degrees_steps_anti_clockwise
                    cvSaveImage((i++)+"-capture.jpg", img);
                    // show image on window
                    canvas.showImage(img);
                }
                 //Thread.sleep(INTERVAL);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/googlecode/javacpp/Pointer
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at camera.Camera.main(Camera.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlecode.javacpp.Pointer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 13 more
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: Please tell us you have at least googled the error message...

Comment: yes I have already done that.but I couldn't find answer yet.

Comment: Please show your `Camera` class in `camera` package.

Comment: public class Camera {
    public static void main(String[] args) {      
        GrabberShow gb = new GrabberShow();
        
    }
    
}

Comment: You're using a very old version of JavaCPP. Please try to upgrade to the latest version first.

Answer (score 0):

Add javacpp jar in your classpath or place in the lib folder

Comment: Could it be as simple as you not importing it?

Comment: echo classpath and check the jar is there in the classpath.

Comment: This link will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970388/why-base64-class-is-not-found-when-code-compiles-ok-and-classpath-is-set?rq=1